# How to publish the registered application to the outside?

Tags: office-addins, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to make a desktop application that has [Supported account types] registered in [Accounts in any organizational directory] for application registration available to users other than my own domain.

Where can I find instructions on how to publish the registered app to the outside world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you are looking for how multi-tenant app works in other tenants.

You can do the [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) for other tenants using the admin consent endpoint (access the following url in a browser):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of other tenants}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id of the multi-tenant app}
```

Sign in with the admin account from other tenants to do the admin consent. This will added an enterprise app to that tenant.

Then you can use it for the authentication in those tenants.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

It was a slightly different transition than I had imagined, but it was added to the enterprise apps of other tenants.